# On table cell click, change to select box

Tags: angular, angular10

I'm trying to change a table cell to a select box on click. This is what I have so far but it seems very, very clunky. Am I missing something in Angular2 that will better serve my needs?

**account-page.component.html**

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource | async" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="payee">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Payee </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let transaction" (click)="onClick()">
            <p [ngStyle]="{'display': show === false ? 'block' : 'none'}">{{transaction.payee.name}}</p>
            <mat-select [ngStyle]="{'display': show === true ? 'block' : 'none'}">
                <mat-option value="{{transaction.payee.name}}">{{transaction.payee.name}}</mat-option>
                <mat-option>Test</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </td>
    </ng-container>
</table>
```

**account-page.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { TransactionsService } from 'src/app/core/services/transactions.service';
import { concatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-account-page',
  templateUrl: './account-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./account-page.component.css']
})
export class AccountPageComponent implements OnInit {

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['payee'];
  dataSource: Observable<any[]>;
  show = false;

  transactions$: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private transactionService: TransactionsService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.transactions$ = this.getTransactions();
    this.dataSource = this.getTransactions();
  }

  getTransactions(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.route.params.pipe(concatMap(params =>  {
      const accountId = params.id;
      return this.transactionService.getTransactionsByAccountId(accountId);
    }));
  }

  onClick() {
    console.log('clicked');
    this.show = !this.show;
  }

}
```

This is obviously a MVP. Name/payee column is where I'd like it to display as text in a table cell; however, when clicked, it dynamically changes to a `<select>/<mat-select>`. Basically it just changes the display properties of `<p>` and `<select>` elements and flip flops the display css. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm getting you right here.

If you want to change the elements, that are shown in your table dynamically, then I would recommend you to use structural directives like `*ngIf` (https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives) instead of the `[ngStyle]='display'` attribute.

For example someting like this:

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource | async" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="payee">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Payee </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let transaction" (click)="onClick()">
            <p *ngIf="!show">{{transaction.payee.name}}</p>
            <mat-select *ngIf="show">
                <mat-option value="{{transaction.payee.name}}">{{transaction.payee.name}}</mat-option>
                <mat-option>Test</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </td>
    </ng-container>
</table>
```

If that wasn't your question, then please give me some more details.

Comment: Doh! Don't know how I missed this. Much better and exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you!